# Android: Set maximum volume

Tags: java, android, volume

I am creating simple alarm application which tests if user does not move with device. If does, Service plays alarm sound.

Problem is, if user set volume to some low values (or mute it). Even if I use this next code, my application uses this volume setting.

```
player = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.sound);
audioManager = (AudioManager)getSystemService(AUDIO_SERVICE);
userVolume = this.audioManager.getStreamVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_ALARM);

audioManager.setStreamVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_ALARM, this.audioManager.getStreamMaxVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_ALARM), AudioManager.FLAG_PLAY_SOUND);
```

Is there a way how to set "master" volume?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `player.setVolume(leftVolume, rightVolume);`

Eg: `player.setVolume(100, 100);`